# How to use animations as window effects in Compiz?

Tags: compiz, animations

I recently installed the `compiz-plugins-extra` in Ubuntu 12.04, And I have animations add-on enabled, But none of the extra features (such as airplane, dissolve, explode, etc.) work. Is there something else I need to install to make these work or what?

Answer (score 2):

After you enable the animation add-ons, logout and login again. That's how they appeared for me.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and open it by typing `ccsm` in the dash. In the CCSM's window, in the effects tab, in the `animations` settings, you can change the various animations type for open windows, close windows, minimize and various others.[image]

and also see this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable both the "Animations" and "Animations Add-On" plugin in the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Can you verify you are actually running Compiz? Run this command in a terminal: `pidof compiz`. If you don't get any output, you are running Unity 2D, which uses Metacity, in stead of Compiz. Which means that none of the Compiz plugins/effects will work for you. If you get a number as output, you're running Compiz, and my doing what I stated above should work.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes compiz won't renew itself when activating plugins. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `compiz --replace` to reload compiz. This is a faster option than logging out and in.